# Codeception 404 on Plesk Shared Hosting

Tags: curl, http-status-code-404, plesk, acceptance-testing, codeception

I'm just trying to get myself going with Codeception.

Got it all installed and have a basic acceptance test to see if it works.

So I run...

php codecept.phar run

...and it goes through all the motions, but the test fails because it 404s.

When I hit the same URL in a browser or wget it from another server it works just fine.

If it makes any difference, the place I'm trying to get this running is on a shared hosting environment running Plesk 11.5.30. The server belongs to the agency I'm working for, so I should be able to get changes made if necessary.

Can anyone help here?

UPDATE

There's definitely an issue using curl, wget etc. on a Plesk server when the URL is pointing to the same server. Same commands work just fine from other servers. I've got our server admin looking at this and I reckon that once the curl issue is sorted, the acceptance tests will probably work.

Comment: I wonder why the -1 vote?

Comment: Currently the Parallels/Plesk guys are looking into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what made it work on our server...

Edit /etc/hosts

Then add a line for the domain NATing it through the local IP:

123.123.123.123  domain.com

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Our /etc/hosts had an entry pointing out domain to 127.0.0.1.  I removed that entry and it all started working again.